# How to invoke subclass method after putting an object from subclass in array of type super class?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes - "Student" and "Employee" which both extends class Person.
All 3 classes have methods inside them.
In my demo class I have to create 2 objects from each class (Student, Employee and Person) and to put them in array of type Person. Then I have to go through the array and depending if the object is from Student, Employee or Person, I have to call a method within this class/subclass. The problem is that once those object go in the array of Person, only the .methods from class Person are visible. How can I make my array[i]."method" be found if it is from Student or Employee (array[i].showStudentInfo() and array[i].showEmplyeeInfo()) 
Thank you in advance!

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean isMan;

    Person(String name, int age, boolean isMan) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isMan = isMan;
    }

    void showPersonInfo() {
        System.out.println("Име: " + this.name + " | " + "години: " + this.age + " | " + "мъж ли е: " + this.isMan);
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {
    double score;

    Student(String name, int age, boolean isMan, double score) {
        super(name, age, isMan);
        this.score = score;
    }
    public void showStudentInfo() {
        System.out.println("Име: " + super.name + " | " + "години: " + super.age + " | " + "мъж ли е: " + " | "
                + super.isMan + " | " + "Оценка: " + this.score);
    }
}

public class Employee extends Person {
double daySallary;
double extraSum;
Employee(String name, int age, boolean isMan, double daySallary){
    super(name, age, isMan);
    this.daySallary=daySallary;
}
    double calculateOvertime(double hours) {
        if (this.age< 18)
            extraSum = 0;
        else
            extraSum = (this.daySallary / 8) * hours * 1.5;
        return extraSum;
    }
    public void showEmployeeInfo() {
        System.out.println("Име: " + super.name + " | " + "години: " + super.age + " | " + "мъж ли е: " + " | "
                + super.isMan + " | " + "Допълнителна сума от оставане след работно време: " + this.extraSum);
    }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person ivan = new Person("Ivan Georgiev", 27, true);
        Person nikola = new Person("Nikola Ivanov", 30, true);
        Student iskra = new Student("Iskra Dimitrova", 21, false, 4.5);
        Student georgi = new Student("Georgi Kazakov", 19, true, 5.5);
        Employee neli = new Employee("Anelia Stoicheva", 35, false, 50);
        Employee monika = new Employee("Monika Petrova", 42, false, 80);

        Person[] array = new Person[10];
        array[0] = ivan;
        array[1] = nikola;
        array[2] = iskra;
        array[3] = georgi;
        array[4] = neli;
        array[5] = monika;


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (array[i].getClass().equals(ivan.getClass())) {
                array[i].showPersonInfo();
            }
            if (array[i].getClass().equals(iskra.getClass())) {

                array[i].showStudentInfo();
            }
            if (array[i].getClass().equals(neli.getClass())) {

                array[i].showEmployeeInfo();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you **know** the type of `Person` you're working with, you can cast the object to the right type: `((Student) array[i]).showStudentInfo()`

Comment: Your design may work better, however, if you have `Person` declare a simple `showInfo()` method and override it in the child classes.

Comment: use `instanceOf` or even better from an OOP perspective add and abstract `showInfo` method to the super class and call that on every element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, since you are already confirming what type of `Person` you're working on during each iteration of your loop, you could simply cast the `Person` to either `Employee` or `Student` as needed:

```
if (array[i].getClass().equals(iskra.getClass())) {
    ((Student)array[i]).showStudentInfo();
}
```

---

However, a better idea would be to follow a more standard Object-Oriented Programming model. Since all the classes that extend from `Person` would have a method to show info, you should declare that method in your `Person` class and have the children override it.

By declaring a `showInfo()` method in your `Person` class, you ensure it is accessible to your `for` loop, regardless of which kind of `Person` you're working with.

---

**Person Class:**

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    int age;
    boolean isMan;

    Person(String name, int age, boolean isMan) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isMan = isMan;
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println("Име: " + this.name + " | " + "години: " + this.age + " | " + "мъж ли е: " + this.isMan);
    }

    // SETTERS and GETTERS
}
```

**Student Class:**

```
public class Student extends Person {

    double score;

    Student(String name, int age, boolean isMan, double score) {
        super(name, age, isMan);
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println("Име: " + super.name + " | " + "години: " + super.age + " | " + "мъж ли е: " + " | "
                + super.isMan + " | " + "Оценка: " + this.score);
    }

    // SETTERS and GETTERS
}
```

**Employee Class:**

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    double daySallary;
    double extraSum;

    Employee(String name, int age, boolean isMan, double daySallary) {
        super(name, age, isMan);
        this.daySallary = daySallary;
    }

    double calculateOvertime(double hours) {
        if (this.age < 18)
            extraSum = 0;
        else
            extraSum = (this.daySallary / 8) * hours * 1.5;
        return extraSum;
    }

    @Override
    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println("Име: " + super.name + " | " + "години: " + super.age + " | " + "мъж ли е: " + " | "
                + super.isMan + " | " + "Допълнителна сума от оставане след работно време: " + this.extraSum);
    }
}
```

---

From there, you can update your `Demo` class to simply call the `showInfo()` method on each `Person`, without having to specifically check for the type of `Person` first:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].showInfo();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Zephyr! Means a lot to me!